# Webpack / Typescript not correctly parsing for-await loop

Tags: typescript, webpack, async-await, vue-cli-3

Hitting a snag with `yarn build` in my vue-cli typescript project:

`tmpDataDocs` is an array of `Promise<DisplayableData>` objects. As far as I understand the `for await` control structure, the type of `doc` inside the loop should be the resolved `DisplayableData` object, not `Promise<DisplayableData>`.

VSCode doesn't have any problem with this loop, `yarn serve` doesn't have a problem with the loop. Only `build` is stumbling.

```bsh
    195:35 Argument of type 'Promise<DisplayableData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DisplayableData'.
      Property 'id_datashape' is missing in type 'Promise<DisplayableData>'.
        193 |     for await (const doc of tmpDataDocs) {
        194 |       tmpData.unshift(
      > 195 |         displayableDataToViewData(doc)
            |                                   ^
        196 |       );
        197 |     }
        198 |
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the build?

Answer (score 0):

An unsatisfying answer: rewrite the code so that it doesn't use the `for-await` construct.

```
// builds successfully
for (const docPromise of tmpDataDocs) {
  const doc = await docPromise;

  tmpData.unshift(
    displayableDataToViewData(doc)
  );
}
```

Comment: `for await` consumes an object that implements the [`Symbol.asyncIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) interface. If your `tmpDataDocs` is just an iterable of promises, you can use `for (const docPromise of await Promise.all(tmpDataDocs))`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `await` could be used there. Mostly throwing stuff at the wall right now.